# The given key was not present in the dictionary when trying to compare value from textbox to value in database

Tags: c#, mysql

I am creating an application where I create user account and im trying to check if there already are identical username in a database, so there wouldn't be a conflict, but whenever i check it, i get "The given key was not present in the dictionary" exeption.

I've found that adding charset to connection string might help, but it didn't helped me. I`ve had similar problem in other part of program and there this solution worked

this is my connection string

```
MySqlConnection Connection = new MySqlConnection(@"server=localhost;user id=root;database=bdiuser;password=password;charset=utf8;");
```

and this is code where i check if there are identical username

```
MySqlCommand checkUsername = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Count(*) FROM userd WHERE username = @Username", Connection);
checkUsername.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", regiUsername.Text);
Connection.Open();
int result = (int)checkUsername.ExecuteScalar();
if (result > 0)
{
    ....
}
```

I expect that, if there are identical value in database, result variable will be bigger than 0 but it returns error in "int result = (int)checkUsername.ExecuteScalar();" row

Comment: Can you at least open the connection? I doubt it, look at your connection string again... `user* id` what is this? Take a look over at [ConnectionStrings website](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/)...

Comment: yes, i can. i was litle bit nervous and made a typo. Connection works well and writes data to database perfectly, but not when i`m trying to extract something

Comment: are you aware that ExecuteScalar returns a null reference if the result set is empty:

Comment: well it's not the case here. i've just tried to just read data from db(the way it works with another table) and it gives the same error. and i've tried to change result variable to var type instead of int type but it won't help - there's something wrong with reading data from database